# Cannot install regular files for Yocto using CMake

Tags: cmake, yocto

I have been using autotools for a few years, and I'm learning CMake now for new projects.

Here is what I have:

myfirstrecipe.bb:

```
inherit pkgconfig cmake
...
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${datadir}/folder1/folder2
    install -m 0755 ${S}/files/file.txt ${D}${datadir}/folder1/folder2
}
```

mysecondrecipe.bb:

```
...
DEPENDS = "myfirstrecipe"
...
```

This works fine. The second recipe can find the file.txt installed by the first recipe, which I see it is installed in the secondrecipe sysroot:

```
build/tmp/work/armv7ahf-vfp-os-linux-musleabi/mysecondrecipe/510-r0/mysecondrecipe-sysroot/usr/share/folder1/folder2/file.txt
```

However I want CMake to install the file instead. So when I try this:

myfirstrecipe.bb:

```
inherit pkgconfig cmake
...
OECMAKE_TARGET_INSTALL = "file-install"
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_custom_target(file-install)
add_custom_command(TARGET file-install POST_BUILD 
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/folder1/folder2
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/files/file.txt
                ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/folder1/folder2/)
```

Then I get a build error from mysecondrecipe.bb saying it could not find the file since it is not installed. I see it installed here:

```
build/tmp/work/armv7ahf-vfp-os-linux-musleabi/myfirstrecipe/1.0-r0/myfirstrecipe-1.0/share/folder1/folder2/file.txt
```

But not in the path above. Anyone can see what I am missing? If I were to use Autotools I could easily get this working with this:

Automake.am:

```
file-install: $(shell find files/ -type f -name '*.txt')
    mkdir -p ${DESTDIR}${datadir}/folder1/folder2
    cp -u $^ -t ${DESTDIR}${datadir}/folder1/folder2
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you do not use the standard way of installing files.
CMake has an **install** directive [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/install.html), wich is commonly used and powerfull.

Doing so, leads to the nice situation, that Within *myfirstrecipe.bb* an own *do_install* task is not necessary. The **cmake.bbclass**, you already inherit, is adding a *do_install* task and relies on the **install** directive within your CMakeLists.txt

You can take a look at the cmake.bbclass to see how it is implemented. It's at poky/meta/classes/cmake.bbclass

I guess that switching to **install** will make life easier